# Unable to open multiple documents in Word or Pages using Command-O in OS X 10.9.4

Tags: macos, applications, ms-office

When using Microsoft Word 2011 on a Mac PowerBook running 10.9.4 I am unable to use the Command-Open command to open more than one file at a time. I can open each file, one at a time, but if I drag several files and drop them on the Word icon or use Command-Open, only the first two files open.

Comment: Same problem with Pages: cannot open multiple .docx files using Command-Open or by dropping files on Pages icon.

Comment: Is your setting to open in NEW window ?

Comment: How big are the documents? Does it make any difference if you only open several small files?

Comment: File size doesn't matter. I can open one at a time but if I have a folder with twenty .docx files and select them all and enter Command-Open or drop them all on the Dock icon only the first one or two files open.

Comment: @wbericson Does this affect other applications? If you select multiple XLS files and try to open them in Excel does it only open the first two?

Comment: No problem with Excel files. Definitely a problem with .docx using either Pages or Word. Uninstalling and reinstalling new copy of Office 2011 did not help and Disk Repair did not help.

Comment: Does this just affect DOCX files? Do DOC files open okay?

Comment: Neither Pages nor Word will open multiple files of .docx. Word will open multiple .doc files, but Pages will not.

Comment: Strange problem. This doesn't help much but at least it is someone else reporting the same problem. [Help! Lion won't let me open multiple selected files!](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1330934)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in either Word or the OS. I've seen this behavior since Lion at least, and have been dealing with it myself just today. Have you tried re-associating file types for Word documents? After setting .doc and .docx files to open in Word by default (Get Info --> Open with --> select or re-select Word, then click Change All), I can launch multiple files again without any problems. It may not be a permanent fix, but it works for me.

If you hadn't mentioned that this affects Pages as well I would blame MS Word, but given this, and that reassociating files seems to help, it sounds like an issue with the way the OS is handling these file types.